# Is it possible to run a vector autoregression analysis on a large GDP data with 58 rows and (time series) and 10467 columns?

Tags: python

l have a large GDP dataset and l am trying to run a VAR model on it. It contains 48 GDP indicators for all the countries in the world, which total 194. So each country has its own indicator value. Meaning each country has its own 48 columns. The time series spreads from 1950 to 2017. With the indicator values for each country. So it's quite a large dataset. Since this is my very first code for var modelling in python. l am having multiple issues with the process.

l tried to run the Granger-causality test on the dataset, but it this error exog contains inf or nans.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import grangercausalitytests
maxlag=12

test = 'ssr-chi2test'

def grangers_causality_matrix(data, variables, test = 'ssr_chi2test', verbose=False):

    dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(variables), len(variables))), columns=variables, index=variables)

    for c in dataset.columns:
        for r in dataset.index:
            test_result = grangercausalitytests(data[[r,c]], maxlag=maxlag, verbose=False)
            p_values = [round(test_result[i+1][0][test][1],4) for i in range(maxlag)]
            if verbose: print(f'Y = {r}, X = {c}, P Values = {p_values}')

            min_p_value = np.min(p_values)
            dataset.loc[r,c] = min_p_value

    dataset.columns = [var + '_x' for var in variables]

    dataset.index = [var + '_y' for var in variables]

    return dataset

grangers_causality_matrix(dataset, variables = dataset.columns)
```

> MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I can only guess that you have missing values in your dataset (which is not surprising : I would not expect to have 48 different GDP indicators available for small countries every year since 1950).

You should find a strategy to deal with these missing values. It is clearly not an easy task. Among the possibilities :

- Replace them with the average value of the column (naive)
- Linearly regress them (hard to know if it's relevant at all)
- Delete all columns or all lines with missing values (brutal)

Some other methods are more subtle but also more difficult to put in place. I'm sure you can find them on the net with the keywords `missing values`. Good luck !

Comment: would placing random numbers work cause l tried to place zeros and when l did that, it showed me the error at hand.

Comment: Best way to know is to test, but I don't think so. Also check if you have `inf` values

Comment: It worked for the adfuller test, l change the inf/nan values to random values and it worked. But now for the cointegration test l am getting a memory error ( MemoryError: ) l am not sure what this means but l think it has something to do with memory.

Comment: Yes, it's more than probable ;) Your table may be too large for the test. Try removing some countries first to see if it works with a dozen countries.

Comment: If the problem is solved, I'd be happy that you validate my answer.

Comment: from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen
data = dataset_train[slice(0, 12, 1)]
jres = coint_johansen(data, det_order=0, k_ar_diff=1)

Comment: l ran the code above and it gives me a memory error still, l sliced my dataset to only 12 variables.

Comment: For this part, I really don't know, I've never encountered the granger causality test before...

Comment: but are you familiar with vector autoregression?

Comment: I know what it is and what it's used for, but not how it works internally. I have no idea if it's memory efficient or not. Your question was  more about missing values that autoregression, that's why I answered it.